# Simple Pdf Viewer using CGPDF

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgpdf

I need to create a  pdf viewer application in iOS .I found using Quartz CGPDF can achieve this  I can't found a proper start . I checked apple documentation .https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html . Can anyone suggest any sample code or tutorial regarding this . I don't want to display pdf in a web view or don't want to use any third party framework .

Thanks in Advance .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked well for me. Given, it was on the Apple TV, but it does not use WebKit, and I'm sure it works just as well on iOS. It draws a PDF using CGPDF from either a local source or from a URL.

[Rendering PDF in Apple TV tvOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34535769/rendering-pdf-in-apple-tv-tvos)

Also want to point out that where it says `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size)`, I replaced this with `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(pageRect.size, NO, 5.0);` because I found that the CGPDF image created is very fuzzy and blurry. By beginning the contxt with options, you can change the scale factor (`5.0`) and this increases the number of pictures, increasing the resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the 'ZoomingPDFViewer' project in the Apple sample code.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ZoomingPDFViewer/Introduction/Intro.html