# Rendering PDF in Apple TV tvOS

Tags: pdf, tvos

I am working on an addition to my tvOS app that would allow viewing of PDFs stored in the app.  However, without UIWebView, I'm at a loss on how to do this.  I've asked question in other places, and get greeted with a link to a wordy and helpless document from Apple about the APIs that can be used, and even here it has been referenced (CGPDFPage) but no real guide on how to implement this.  Has anyone successfully done this on tvOS, and if so, would you help me get started in this process?

Comment: What's the link you get sent to? Having CGPDFPage normally won't help you as it contains only "metadata" information about the page but by itself can't render its contents. It's normally CGContext which has the ability to take such a page and render it; but that might very well be one of the API's not available (See here if it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639781/rendering-a-cgpdfpage-into-a-uiimage)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Below is some code that I wrote and tested in tvOS. Note that this is in Objective-c.

I've created two functions to do the job, and one helper function to display the PDF images in a UIScrollView. The first one will open the PDF document from a URL. A web URL was used. A local file could also be used in this sample.

There is also a helper function to open a document from a local file.

The second function renders the PDF document to a context. I chose to display the context by creating an image from it. There are other ways of handling the context too.

Opening the document is fairly straight forward, so there are no comments in the code for that. Rendering the document is slightly more involved, and so there are comments explaining that function.

The complete application is below.

```
- (CGPDFDocumentRef)openPDFLocal:(NSString *)pdfURL {
    NSURL* NSUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfURL];
    
    return [self openPDF:NSUrl];
}

- (CGPDFDocumentRef)openPDFURL:(NSString *)pdfURL {
    NSURL* NSUrl= [NSURL URLWithString:pdfURL];
    
    return [self openPDF:NSUrl];
}

- (CGPDFDocumentRef)openPDF:(NSURL*)NSUrl {
    CFURLRef url = (CFURLRef)CFBridgingRetain(NSUrl);
    
    CGPDFDocumentRef myDocument;
    myDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(url);
    if (myDocument == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"can't open %@", NSUrl);
        CFRelease (url);
        return nil;
    }
    CFRelease (url);
    
    if (CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(myDocument) == 0) {
        CGPDFDocumentRelease(myDocument);
        return nil;
    }
    
    return myDocument;
}
- (void)drawDocument:(CGPDFDocumentRef)pdfDocument
{
    // Get the total number of pages for the whole PDF document
    int  totalPages= (int)CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdfDocument);
    NSMutableArray *pageImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    // Iterate through the pages and add each page image to an array
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalPages; i++) {
        // Get the first page of the PDF document
        CGPDFPageRef page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdfDocument, i);
        CGRect pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, kCGPDFMediaBox);
        
        // Begin the image context with the page size
        // Also get the grapgics context that we will draw to
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        
        // Rotate the page, so it displays correctly
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, pageRect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
        CGContextConcatCTM(context, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, pageRect, 0, true));
        
        // Draw to the graphics context
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);
        
        // Get an image of the graphics context
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        [pageImages addObject:image];
    }
    // Set the image of the PDF to the current view
    [self addImagesToScrollView:pageImages];
}

-(void)addImagesToScrollView:(NSMutableArray*)imageArray {
    int height = 0;
    int width = 0 ;
    for (UIImage *image in imageArray) {
        UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
        imgView.frame=CGRectMake(0, height, imgView.frame.size.width, imgView.frame.size.height);
        [_scrollView addSubview:imgView];
        if(imgView.frame.size.width > width) width = imgView.frame.size.width ;
        height += imgView.frame.size.height;
    }
    
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height) ;
    self.scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES ;
    self.scrollView.userInteractionEnabled = YES ;
    self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes =  @[ @(UITouchTypeIndirect) ];
}
```

And to tie it all together, you can do this:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument = [self openPDFURL:@"http://www.guardiansuk.com/uploads/accreditation/10testing.pdf"];
[self drawDocument:pdfDocument];
```

Note that I'm using a random PDF that was available for free on the web. I ran into some problems with https URLs, but I'm sure this can be resolved, and it's not actually related to the PDF opening question.

Comment: Thank you. I will give this a go when I get back. Most of PDFs should be stored within the app (think I can get it in and still be under 200Mb limit)

Comment: Quick question...I have the app available in the store now with just using Video features and as a TVML app.  To run it like this, would it need to be a Custom app?

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't really work, as nearly every PDF involved in this project has multiple pages.

Comment: I've edited the code the use a multi page document. The new code uses an array to store the image for each page. Then a UIScrollView to display all of the images. Note that if you are using auto layout (you should be), there are some specifics around getting the UIScrollView to increase with the content. Let me know if you can't get it right, and I'll try to help.

Comment: Wanted to mention that you can display the array of UIImage (the pages of the document) in many different ways, depending on the presentation you are after. UIPageViewController would be another great way of displaying them. It might be a bit more involved than using a UIScrollView, but the result would be better.

Comment: Thanks!  That's sweet.  I was able to get the scrollview contentSize set by just multiplying the height of 1080 by the number of pages.  The only issue I have is related more to the Tab nature of the application.  I'm awarding the bounty, but wonder (since you have dealt with tvOS and ScrollView before), how do you deal with the Tab bar constantly re-appearing if I scroll too far up on the trackpad?  When it shows back up, it won't allow me to scroll until I change focus again.

Comment: Happy this worked for you. The first spot I'd look for a solution about the tab bar issue would be auto layout. Make sure your constraints are set up properly. UIScrollView is a bit different with auto layout than without. If you are not familiar, there are some great guides available online that I can help you with that. You could also be running into a problem with having too many images (pages). If that's the case, I would consider buffering some of them, and doing the rendering and display in chunks.

Comment: Last question ( I Hope).  How would code change if instead of online PDF, I do local?  I removed the URL in favor of the path where the PDF is stored in the app, but it just crashes.

Comment: No worries. I've modified the code slightly to accommodate for local files. Now you can use openPDFLocal() to open a local file or openPDFURL() to open a web URL. You will see that there is a slight difference. To open a local file, you need to use NSURL fileURLWithPath: when creating the NSURL. This is what I used to get the path to a file in the bundle [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"" ofType:@"pdf"]. There are other options depending on the file location. Hope this helps!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99850/discussion-between-user717452-and-vel-genov).

Comment: Resolution of the image is too low. How to get high resolution ?

Comment: I've been using this, but every once in a while, I come across an issue where it won't draw the PDF, and it seems to be related to downloading the PDF is still in progress when it attempts to draw it. Is there a completion handler that could work?

Answer (score 2):

The tvOS documentation contains a section on [creating, viewing and transforming PDF documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_pdf/dq_pdf.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH214-TPXREF101) so I think it contains the functionality you need.

There’s lots of example code on that page, but here’s some code I use on iOS for the same purpose. It should work on tvOS, but I don’t have a way to test it:

```
func imageForPDF(URL: NSURL, pageNumber: Int, imageWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(URL)
    let page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(document, pageNumber)
    var pageRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(page, .MediaBox)
    let scale = imageWidth / pageRect.size.width
    pageRect.size = CGSizeMake(pageRect.size.width * scale, pageRect.size.height * scale)
    pageRect.origin = CGPointZero

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size)
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(ctx, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0) // White background
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, pageRect)
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx)

    // Rotate the PDF so that it’s the right way around
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0.0, pageRect.size.height)
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1.0, -1.0)
    CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, .MediaBox, pageRect, 0, true))

    CGContextDrawPDFPage(ctx, page)
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is @jbg's answer in swift 5

```html
func imageForPDF(URL: NSURL, pageNumber: Int, imageWidth: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        guard let document = CGPDFDocument(URL) else { return nil }
        guard let page = document.page(at: pageNumber) else { return nil }
        var pageRect = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox)
        let scale = imageWidth / pageRect.size.width
        pageRect.size = CGSize(width: pageRect.size.width * scale,
                               height: pageRect.size.height * scale)
        pageRect.origin = CGPoint.zero
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pageRect.size)
        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()  else { return nil }
        context.setFillColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
        context.fill(pageRect)
        context.saveGState()
        
        // Rotate the PDF so that it’s the right way around
        context.translateBy(x: 0.0, y: pageRect.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        context.concatenate(page.getDrawingTransform(.mediaBox, rect: pageRect, rotate: 0, preserveAspectRatio: true))
        
        context.drawPDFPage(page)
        context.restoreGState()
        
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
```

`